# TFS - Reference Filepath of Downloaded Secure File

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, yaml

I have a Build Pipeline in Azure DevOps where I am downloaded a secure key file. In my next step, I want to reference the filepath of this newly downloaded file with a Command Line Script task such as:
`sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --jwtfile $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH`

The problem is that the environment variable does not seem to exist-- the Script is taking the literal plaintext of "`$env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH`" rather than transposing the filepath as I am expecting. I should note that I am not using full YAML, I am using the new "Visual Designer" interface.
Has anyone done this in the past?
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a typo: `sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --jwtfile $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH`. Note that you only have one colon after `$env`.

Comment: I added an extra colon for a total of two, which the same effect.

Comment: Wait a second. If you're running it from a `Command Line` task, then it's not PowerShell. `$env::...` is PowerShell syntax. Try `%DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH%`. Or if this is a non-Windows agent (say, a Bash script), just `$DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.. I knew it had to be something tremendously obvious...

Comment: @DanielMann please provide your comment as answer, so that the OP can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running it from a Command Line task, then it's not PowerShell. `$env::...` is PowerShell syntax. Try `%DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH%`. Or if this is a non-Windows agent (say, a Bash script), just `$DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH`

Comment: are you sure there should be two colons? This works for me in Powershell $secureFile = "$env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE_SECUREFILEPATH"